# How does one monitor all bitcoin address that hold more than a certain amount and detect movement from cold storage?

Tags: mtgox, sell-bitcoins, chainanalysis

Is there a service or site where one can monitor all large bitcoin hodler addresses to detect movement? And as seen below with the mt.gox trustee moving coins from his cold storage. How does one find out when a mass exodus of cold storage movement happens?

[image]

Comment: Build yourself : https://bitcore.io/guides/satoshi-fire-alarm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this website shows all movement from mtgox cold wallets with one day delay or real time when you donate:
https://www.cryptoground.com/mtgox-cold-wallet-monitor/

Answer (score 1):

There are sites that monitor the blockchain and aggregate the data. E.g. https://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-bitcoin-addresses.html